# Specify Provider in XMlLDigital Signature API

Tags: xml-signature

I want to sign an xml document usign XMl Digital Signature API in Java.

Is there any method to specify custom  provider instead of JCE Provider

Comment: Could you please accept some answers on your last questions (you can vote up as well, if helpful). Please at least indicate what is wrong or missing if the answer is not complete or helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the Apache Santuario JSR-105 Provider (instead of Oracle's), you could use

`String providerName = "org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI"; 
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());`

Caveat emptor http://santuario.apache.org/java150releasenotes.html#java_1_5_0_release_notes-JSR105providerhasbeenrenamed